# Reset properties jquery

Tags: jquery, transition

I've got the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
document.ontouchmove = function(e) {e.preventDefault()};

// *************** NAVEGACION **************************

$('.botMenu').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    $(this).transition({ scale: 1.2},200);
    $('#section_'+ index).css('display','block');
    $('.section').transition({opacity : '0'},400);
    $('#section_'+ index).transition({opacity : '1'},400, 'snap');


    $('#section_'+ index).transition({perspective: '100px',rotateX: '180deg'});


    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).transition({ scale: 1.0},200);
    },400);
});
});
```

The problem is that the transitions are done just in the first click and I want to do de effect every time I click it.
I thought to do some kind of event that resets all the propieties in order to be done again, is it possible?

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net). Also never heard of transition.  Is that a plugin?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gUzv2/ I'm not sure I'm new using jquery but in fact what i'm doing is to create an script with css propieties using jquery